# matInput how to error treatment on the inputs on valuechange subscription

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm using Angular 7x and angular material.  I have a formGroup that only has one input. I get the value changed event as the user types and the validation is firing but I don't get the visual treatment of an error until I tab out or the page loses focus.

The interesting thing is that once I do tab out/lose focus and come back to the form everything works as expected.

[image]

[image: The Form Setup]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be doing something like this:

```html
<form [formGroup]="userOptionsForm">
  <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
    <mat-label>User Handle</mat-label>
    <div matPrefix>@</div>
    <input matInput 
           formControlName="userHandle"
           minlength="4"
           maxlength="24"
           required>
    <mat-error *ngIf="userOptionsForm?.get('userHandle')?.errors">
      {{getErrorMessage()}}
    </mat-error>
    <mat-hint>Your mixes as authored by...</mat-hint>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

One important behavior is that `mat-error` isn't shown until the input is touched. To achieve that after creating the form, programmatically, you must do the following:

```js
constructor(_fb: FormBuilder) {
  this.userOptionsForm = _fb.group({
    userHandle: ['', [Validators.required, 
        Validators.minLength(4), Validators.maxLength(24)]]
  });

  this._form.get('userHandle')!.markAsTouched();
}
```

[Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/httpsstackoverflowcoma614340646433166)

Comment: No success. I did exactly this.  I verified in my value changed that the userOptions.get(userhandle).errors has a value when it has an error and null when it does not, so the validator and the form set up is correct.  even went so far as to add a simple bool that is set on the ngIf for userHandleHasError on the mat-error.  But still no error visual until I tab out, at least once.  I know the flags and the form are correct, i'm just not getting the mat-error effect.

Comment: Maybe you're referring to the first time the user interacts with the form. Usually, you'll show error messages on blur and, from that time on, update the errors on each change. For example, if you collect an email, you likely won't show an error message as soon as the page loads, before the user has a chance to interact with it (it gives him the impression that he made a mistake without even touching the form). But if you really want that, just call `this.userOptionsFor.get('useHandle')!.markAsTouched();` just after creating the form group in the typescript code.

Comment: i tried this. that's not exactly it.  steps to reproduce. 1 field on form, field is valid initially.  user takes action in the field (deleting chars say), making making field invalid. No error highlighting until field loses focus.  come back to field after losing focus, everything works perfect.

Comment: Usually the UX is better if the user doesn't get error messages right after heshe loads the component. Are you sure you want the validation to be fired when the user first changes the control value?

Comment: I just saw the stackblitz now. I'm looking it over.

Comment: I agree with you on the UX. the problem was I wasn't getting the error effect on the initial input. Now,  your stackblitz code works, mine doesn't .can't quite explain why but I'll move over your example.  Thank you so much for taking the time to help and do the stackblitz.

Comment: I achieve that on my stackblitz with this statement: `this._form.get('email')!.markAsTouched();` right after creating the form group. I'll update my answer with this info.